# Regex check for compulsory prefixes +1 or +44 or +2 or 99

Tags: regex

I have following regex that check for compulsory prefix **+** and it works fine.

```
^\+[0-9]+$
```

Now I want it to check for compulsory prefixes **+1** or **+44** or **+2** or **99**

46541324654 (false)

+1465465423646 (true)

+4421326546546654654 (true)

+24654654321323 (true)

+246546543 (true)

**Edit more examples**

+946546543 (false)

+0046546543 (false)

9946546543 (true)

Comment: Your first example looks strange - did you mean `+46...` instead of `46...` ? Otherwise, there's no need to modify your regex at all.

Comment: Did you try to simply add (44|1|2) to your previous regex ? It gives `^\+(44|1|2)[0-9]+$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
^(\+(1|2|44)|99)[0-9]+$
```

Capture testing +946546543
[image]

Comment: The question has been updated. Could you update the answer to match?

Comment: Please review your answer +946546543 must return false.

Comment: it will. I'll add an screenshot. You can test it here https://regex101.com/

Comment: thank you @SCouto for help, please upvote my question if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your `\+` with a sub pattern that matches +44, +2 or +1.

```
^\+(?:44|1|2)[0-9]+$
```